# Динамическое изменение стиля через [ngClass]

Tags: css, angular

Необходимо применять `margin-top` для `input`, но чтобы стиль не применялся на placeholder. т.е. только в том случае, когда заполнен `label`. В `*ngClass` проверять на наличие placeholder в инпуте - если его нет, то добавляется класс

```js
export class PanelComponent {
     @ViewChild('addressInput') adressInput: ElementRef;
     
     setInputStyle() {
        let styles = {
            'margin-top': this.adressInput.placeholder ? '10px' : '20px'
        };
        return styles;
     }
  }
```

```css
.panel__input {
      display: block;
      margin-bottom: 24px;
      input {
        width: 262px !important;
        padding-left: 10px !important;
        padding-right: 40px !important;
      }
}
.panel__input-name {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      padding: 5px 10px;
      font-size: 16px;
    }
```

```html
  <input-container class="panel__input" *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index;">
      <input-prefix>
        {{ point.order }}
      </input-prefix>
      <label><span class="panel__input-name">{{ item.name }}</span>
              <input
               [ngClass]="setInputStyle()"
                #adressInput
                placeholder="начните вводить название"
                [(ngModel)]="item.address"
                (blur)="onBlurInput(item)"/>
            </label>
    </input-container>
```

Comment: А textarea нельзя использовать ?

Comment: поставьте значит тег `css` и уберите тег angular, я не вижу связи между вопросом и меткой

Answer (score 0):

Сделать такую штуку с плейсхолдером, который задаётся как атрибут инпута, вряд ли получится. Но плейсхолдер можно сымитировать, и тогда это будет работать примерно так:

```css
form {
  position: relative;
}
.placeholder {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  color: gray;
}
input {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  transition: .5s;
}
input:focus,
input:valid {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<form>
<input type="text" required />
<span class="placeholder">Введите текст</span>
</form>
```